# Where is the updated Ethereum roadmap?

Tags: casper, homestead, serenity, metropolis

Googling "Ethereum Roadmap" just brings up outdated blog posts.

Where can i find the current, updated roadmap?

Comment: Roadmaps are moving targets and not a good fit for StackExchange. It's better to ask on another site like the [Ethereum reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum).

Answer (score 14):

In his [DEVCON1 Keynote](https://youtu.be/BUARih8_f68?t=3m36s), [Vitalik Buterin](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/188/vitalik-buterin) addressed the roadmap of Ethereum beyond the Frontier release:

- [homestead](/questions/tagged/homestead),
  expected when the ethereum network, miners and other critical components work without serious hiccups for about 4 weeks.
- [metropolis](/questions/tagged/metropolis), with focus on the [mist](/questions/tagged/mist) browser.
- [serenity](/questions/tagged/serenity), Ethereum 2.0, with 4 primary research directions:

  1. [casper](/questions/tagged/casper), the [proof-of-stake](/questions/tagged/proof-of-stake) algorithm.
  2. [scalability](/questions/tagged/scalability), by processing transactions in parallel and moving away from the paradigm where every node in the network has to absolutely process every transaction.
  3. zkSNARK, addressing [privacy](/questions/tagged/privacy).
  4. Upgrading the [evm](/questions/tagged/evm) (Ethereum Virtual Machine).

Comment: Hasn't the condition for homestead been met already?

Comment: @ripper234 [Homestead is a hard-fork](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-2.mediawiki) and hasn't been released yet.  It has additions and is more than just no "hiccups" for a period of time.